# How to trigger an action on specific date even if the app is closed?

Tags: iphone, scheduled-tasks, swift3, ios10, uidatepicker

I am trying to implement a scheduler function in my application using `UIDatePicker` and `dateFormatter` so that when a user select a date and time for the action to run on that specific date, the action should occur even if the app is closed, so how can I achieve same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to (guaranteed) run specific code at a certain time if your app is not running.

It is possible to schedule a local `NSNotification` to inform the user. In case the user triggers your notification, your app is started / woken up by the OS and you can handle it. A nice notification guide can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37830899/1457385)