# Local and Push Notifications in IOS version compatible

Tags: ios, swift, apple-push-notifications, uilocalnotification

I developed `local Notifications` in `iOS 10`. It is working perfectly. But now how should i code `local notifications` and `push notification` if user is using `iOS 9` and above versions. Can anyone help please?

Below is code in `iOS 10`

```
import UIKit
import UserNotifications

@available(iOS 10.0, *)
class ViewController: UIViewController,UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
       super.viewDidLoad()

       if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
        //Seeking permission of the user to display app notifications
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: [.alert,.sound,.badge], completionHandler: {didAllow,Error in })
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self

       }
   }

   //To display notifications when app is running  inforeground
   func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
       completionHandler([.alert, .sound, .badge])
   }

   override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
       super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
       // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
   }

   @IBAction func buttonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {

       if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {

           //Setting content of the notification
           let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
           content.title = "hello"
           content.body = "notification pooped out"
           content.badge = 1

           //Setting time for notification trigger
           let date = Date(timeIntervalSinceNow: 10)
           var dateCompenents = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.year, .month, .day, .hour, .minute, .second], from: date)

           let trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: dateCompenents, repeats: false)
           //Adding Request
           let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: "timerdone", content: content, trigger: trigger)
           UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(request, withCompletionHandler: nil)
        }

     }

 }
```

Comment: What is your issue? What have you tried?

Comment: I need to modify my code such that it also works in iOS9. UserNotifications framework which i used here is only present in iOS 10

Comment: how to set different date components or how to call local notfications multiple times?

Answer (score 45):

**IOS 12** :- Group notification

set `threadIdentifier` `UNMutableNotificationContent` to create group notification

create local notification group

```
let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
content.title = "Group Notifications"
content.body = "Body of notification"
content.threadIdentifier = "group-identifire"
```

create remote notification group need to pass `thread-id` in payload

```
{
 "aps" : {
     "alert" : {
         "title" : "Group Notifications",
         "body" : "Body of notification"
     }
     "thread-id" : "group-identifire"
 }
}
```

**IOS 11** :- You can also use following code for iOS 11. No any kind of changes requires in push and local notification

**Creating A Notification Request**

```
import UserNotifications

if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
    //iOS 10.0 and greater
    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: [.badge, .sound, .alert], completionHandler: { granted, error in
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            if granted {
                UIApplication.shared.registerForRemoteNotifications()
            }
            else {
                //Do stuff if unsuccessful...
            }
        }
   })
}
else { 
    //iOS 9
    let type: UIUserNotificationType = [UIUserNotificationType.badge, UIUserNotificationType.alert, UIUserNotificationType.sound]
    let setting = UIUserNotificationSettings(types: type, categories: nil)
    UIApplication.shared.registerUserNotificationSettings(setting)
    UIApplication.shared.registerForRemoteNotifications()
}
```

**Schedule Local Notification**

```
if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
    //iOS 10 or above version
    let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
    let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
    content.title = "Late wake up call"
    content.body = "The early bird catches the worm, but the second mouse gets the cheese."
    content.categoryIdentifier = "alarm"
    content.userInfo = ["customData": "fizzbuzz"]
    content.sound = UNNotificationSound.default()

    var dateComponents = DateComponents()
    dateComponents.hour = 15
    dateComponents.minute = 49
    let trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: dateComponents, repeats: true)

    let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: UUID().uuidString, content: content, trigger: trigger)
    center.add(request)
} else {
    // ios 9 
    let notification = UILocalNotification()
    notification.fireDate = NSDate(timeIntervalSinceNow: 5) as Date
    notification.alertBody = "Hey you! Yeah you! Swipe to unlock!"
    notification.alertAction = "be awesome!"
    notification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName
    UIApplication.shared.scheduleLocalNotification(notification)
}
```

**UIApplicationDelegate**

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
    let tokenParts = deviceToken.map { data -> String in
        return String(format: "%02.2hhx", data)
    }
    let token = tokenParts.joined()
    print(token)
}

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError error: Error) {

}
```

**UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate**

Only available in ios 10 and above version

The method will be called on the delegate only if the application is in the foreground

You can present default banner with helping of following method

```
@available(iOS 10.0, *)
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
    completionHandler([.badge,.alert,.sound])
}
```

The method will be called on the delegate when the user responded to the notification by opening the application, dismissing the notification or choosing a UNNotificationAction

```
@available(iOS 10.0, *)
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {

}
```

Comment: how to set different date components or how to call local notfications multiple times?

Answer (score 13):

I have made this class for **Swift 3** which has a function for requesting permission to push notification and also a send notification. **Works on for iOS 9 and iOS 10+.**

```
import UIKit
import UserNotifications

class LocalNotification: NSObject, UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {

    class func registerForLocalNotification(on application:UIApplication) {
        if (UIApplication.instancesRespond(to: #selector(UIApplication.registerUserNotificationSettings(_:)))) {
            let notificationCategory:UIMutableUserNotificationCategory = UIMutableUserNotificationCategory()
            notificationCategory.identifier = "NOTIFICATION_CATEGORY"

            //registerting for the notification.
            application.registerUserNotificationSettings(UIUserNotificationSettings(types:[.sound, .alert, .badge], categories: nil))
        }
    }

    class func dispatchlocalNotification(with title: String, body: String, userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any]? = nil, at date:Date) {

        if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {

            let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
            let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
            content.title = title
            content.body = body
            content.categoryIdentifier = "Fechou"

            if let info = userInfo {
                content.userInfo = info
            }

            content.sound = UNNotificationSound.default()

            let comp = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.hour, .minute], from: date)

            let trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: comp, repeats: true)

            let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: UUID().uuidString, content: content, trigger: trigger)

            center.add(request)

        } else {

            let notification = UILocalNotification()
            notification.fireDate = date
            notification.alertTitle = title
            notification.alertBody = body

            if let info = userInfo {
                notification.userInfo = info
            }

            notification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName
            UIApplication.shared.scheduleLocalNotification(notification)

        }

        print("WILL DISPATCH LOCAL NOTIFICATION AT ", date)

    }
}
```

**Usage:**

You can request permission anywhere:

```
LocalNotification.registerForLocalNotification(on: UIApplication.shared)
```

And to dispatch a local notification:

```
LocalNotification.dispatchlocalNotification(with: "Notification Title for iOS10+", body: "This is the notification body, works on all versions", at: Date().addedBy(minutes: 2))
```

**Tip:**

You can set the notification to fire at any future Date, in this example I'm using a date extension to get a future date in minutes to the notification fire. This is it:

```
extension Date {
    func addedBy(minutes:Int) -> Date {
        return Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .minute, value: minutes, to: self)!
    }
}
```