# How to Post a UILocalNotifivcation only once in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, uilocalnotification

Im posting a notification in iOS, I dont want to repeat the notification code i have used is.

```
let notification = UILocalNotification()
notification.timeZone = NSTimeZone.local
//calculation of dateTime
notification.fireDate = dateTime as Date?


notification.repeatInterval = 0

notification.alertBody = "Body"
notification.userInfo = ["title": "Notify", "type": "title", "5436" : "Notify"]
```

In that condition my notification was not firing. When I give like

```
notification.repeatInterval = NSCalendar.Unit.day
```

It is firing.. Is this a feature or issue? How can i post a notification without repeat interval

Comment: I just want to show notification only once and no repeatation needed

Comment: Try this notification.repeatInterval = NSCalendar.Unit(rawValue: 0)

Comment: I would advise debugging the value of `dateTime`

Comment: Where is this `dateTime` coming from? Can you verify if this dateTime is in the future and not in the past?

Comment: @Spynet I dont want to repeat it

Comment: @Surjeet I have tried that also still not working

Comment: Is there any way to cancel the notification inside didReceiveNotification method?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42688966/5461400 @Saranjith

Answer (score 2):

Soultion 1: 
You can use [dispatch_once](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/dispatch/1447169-dispatch_once):

```
static var token: dispatch_once_t = 0

dispatch_once(&token) {
  NSLog("Do it once")
}
```

Solution 2:

Taken from Apple documentation:

> If you assign an calendar unit such as weekly (NSWeekCalendarUnit) or
>   yearly (NSYearCalendarUnit), the system reschedules the notification
>   for delivery at the specified interval. The default value is 0, which
>   means don't repeat.

I assume you want to cancel the notification with the repeating interval, you can do that in two ways:

> Cancel all the notifications.
>
> Cancel only that notification.

The first option is easy, use:

cancelAllLocalNotifications
In your app delegate.

The second one requires more work. You need to go through the pending notifications (use scheduledLocalNotifications) and cancel the notification.

In order to know which notifications is going to be canceled you can use the userInfo property when you set the notification. For example set an unique ID for every notification so when you cancel that notification you simply compare that ID with all the IDs in your scheduledLocalNotifications array.

Comment: Can you explain dispatch_once method.. i m not getting you

Comment: of posting notification right? what should be value of repeat interval?

Comment: @Saranjith  make it as it is just add this line UIApplication.sharedApplication().cancelAllLocalNotifications()
 after your notification.repeatInterval = NSCalendar.Unit.day