# How to detect if user has taken action local notification or remote notification?

Tags: ios, swift, notifications, unusernotificationcenter

I am displaying local and remote notifications in my app. Now there is scenario if the notification is local then I want to take a different action or if the the notification is remote then I want to take some different action.

Till iOS 9 I was using below code to detect if the notification is local or remote.

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {


    if launchOptions?[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey.localNotification] != nil {
        // Do what you want to happen when a remote notification is tapped.
    }
    return true
  }
```

But in iOS 10 this approach is deprecated so now how do I make sure the notification is local or remote ?

Comment: Check this: https://useyourloaf.com/blog/local-notifications-with-ios-10/

Comment: You can check my answer i have updated. Hope this will help.

Answer (score 13):

For iOS 10 and above using `UserNotifications` framework.

To check user has taken an action on a notification. You can conform to `UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate` and implement `userNotificationCenter:didReceiveNotificationResponse:withCompletionHandler:`

To check if it is a remote notification. You can check type of `trigger`, since remote notifications trigger is `UNPushNotificationTrigger`.

Here's the code...

```
#pragma mark - UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate

- (void)userNotificationCenter:(UNUserNotificationCenter *)center
didReceiveNotificationResponse:(UNNotificationResponse *)response
         withCompletionHandler:(void (^)(void))completionHandler {

    if ([response.notification.request.trigger isKindOfClass:[UNPushNotificationTrigger class]]) {
        // User did tap at remote notification
    }

    completionHandler();
}
```

Answer (score 6):

In `UNMutableNotificationContent` add `userInfo` in like below:

```
content.userInfo = ["isLocalNotification" : true]
```

Now in `AppDelegate` set `UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate` in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` like below:

```
UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
```

Then implement `didReceive response` method of `UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate`:

```
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {

        print(response.notification.request.content.userInfo)
    }
```

in output you will get something like below:

**[AnyHashable("isLocalNotification"): 1]**

you can identify Local Notification with `isLocalNotification` key.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer below link. You will get your answer. If not please let me know:

[Local and Push Notifications in IOS 9 and 10 using swift3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42688760/local-and-push-notifications-in-ios-9-and-10-using-swift3)

Further information regarding Notification category:

To identify local and remote notification you can assign an identifier to notification object. `UIMutableUserNotificationCategory` is deprecated in iOS 10, So use `UNNotificationCategory` to assign identifier to notification.

Refer below links for assigning an identifier to notification :

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uimutableusernotificationcategory/
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/unnotificationcategory