# How to generate notifications every special day under different conditions

Tags: ios, swift, notifications

For example, I am working on a Stundenplan, Stundenplan should notify users when there are classes tomorrow or today morning, afternoon and evening. Also notifications should repeat every special weekday if the classes continue for weeks.

Like a alarm alert it is effective to use 
***UNCalendarNotificationTrigger*** 
to let notifications repeat under dateComponents‘ constraint.

However, every class has its start date and end date, between them notifications should repeat, but outside shouldn't notify anymore. So it is not rational to generate one repeating notification for every class when classes was added to Stundenplan. Another better solution is needed for this thorny problem.

Many thanks for your kind advices!

Comment: have you looked at local notifications?

Comment: @saad-chaudhry do you mean local notifications before iOS 10, I have not tried that, by the way I am working with Swift 3

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37807302/add-local-notification-in-ios10-swift-3