# show recording permission alert if it was denied previously

Tags: ios, objective-c, avaudiosession

The [requestRecordPermission](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioSession_ClassReference/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/AVAudioSession/requestRecordPermission:) function memorize user's first time choice & it doesn't show the granting record permission alert if user has previously denied recording permission.

How can I always pop up the granting recording permission alert if previously user denied recording permission?

```
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] requestRecordPermission:^(BOOL granted) {
            if (!granted) {
                // Microphone permission is not granted previously,
                // How to pop up granting alert/dialog again?
                // (My app supports iOS 7 and above)
            }
        }];
```

I know how to detect whether the permission is granted or not, my question is about after recording(microphone) permission has been denied once, how can I present the granting permission alert again to user?

(My app needs to support iOS7 and above)

Answer (score 0):

Actually it's not possible to show permission alert again!

check out this SO post:
[Request permissions again after user denies...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29980832/request-permissions-again-after-user-denies-location-services)

It says-

> The OS will only ever prompt the user once. If they deny permission, that's it.

Answer (score 0):

Following the Apple guidelines, you should simply show a message to the user explaining why he can't use the record feature. 
A simple "How to enable my record permission" will do the job :)