# How to reflect native iOS permission settings for location via a UISwitch?

Tags: ios, swift, core-location, uiswitch

I'm trying out the new CLLocationManager API which will contain "Allow Once". By default my UISwitch is off when I go to the native settings page and select "While Using the App" when I return to the app I want my switch to be enabled. The only time the switch should be off is when the user selects "Never" or "Don't allow" when requestWhenInUseAuthorization() is called.

```
import UIKit
import CoreLocation

class ViewController: UIViewController,CLLocationManagerDelegate {

    let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    let status = CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus()

override func viewDidLoad() {
        locationManager.delegate = self
    }

@IBOutlet weak var toggleSwitch: UISwitch!

    @IBAction func locationToggle(_ sender: Any) {

        if status == .denied || status == .restricted && toggleSwitch.isOn {
            toggleSwitch.setOn(false, animated: false)
        }
        else if status == .authorizedWhenInUse || status == .authorizedAlways {
            toggleSwitch.setOn(true, animated: false)
        }
        else if status == .notDetermined {
            locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29980832/request-permissions-again-after-user-denies-location-services
Look at this example.

Comment: @iamMobile I tried that earlier without any luck :(

Comment: can you confirm if in System Settings you have Location Services enabled?

Comment: Yes when I leave the app it shows that it is enabled accordingly to the setting selected